# Custom helper is not working in codeigniter v3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I create two helper files in helper folder. But when I trying to include both helper I am getting error.

> Unable to load the requested file: helpers/web_helper.php

**MY_array_helper.php**

```
<?php

function print_pre($array= array()){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

**MY_web_helper.php**

```
<?php

function test(){
    echo "working";

}
```

**Welcome.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');



class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('array_helper');
        $this->load->helper('web_helper');
    }
```

Comment: Try renaming your filename to helpers/Web_helper.php first letter upper case. And then `$this->load->helper('web');`

Comment: check `$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_'` what is set??

Comment: You do not need to use the word helper  `$this->load->helper('web_helper');` and  `$this->load->helper('web');`

Comment: yes both are working now

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Autolad` in `application\config\autoload.php`

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('MY_array_helper','MY_web_helper');
```

OR

```
$this->load->helper( array('MY_array_helper', 'MY_web_helper') );
```

Comment: I want to use two custum helper single is working with file name "MY_array_helper" why??

Answer (score 0):

It is working with file name Array_helper.php and Web_helper.php in helper folder  and in autoload file `$autoload['helper'] = array('array','web');`

Comment: All ways remember to use first letter upper case for your file names and classes. That goes for controllers, models, libraries etc.

Comment: Helper is not a class.